# Google images directing to url with Escaped Fragment

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, ajax

I'm running an ajax website with images and using [Google's guidelines for ajax webistes](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling%E2%80%8E).

My site is indexed correctly in Google's web search. But in image search the _escaped_fragment_ appears in the links so that ajax pages are not loaded for the users coming form Google image search.

Any solution for this?

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a bug in Google image search I think.

There by I changed the site script to checked the HTTP_USER_AGENT and if it is not Google or Yahoo or msnbot it will load in Ajax even if the _escaped_fragment_ is detected in the url.

**This is a sad solution.**

not going to mark it as the correct one.